# Flying from/to Geneva with a Schengen type D Spanish visa

Tags: visas, air-travel, schengen, cancellations

I am a Bangladeshi citizen. I came from Geneva airport to Bangladesh with this visa 10 days ago. Now for my return trip they say I must go to Spain first (visa issuing country) rather than going to Geneva! They say it is port of entry rule. Could you please confirm / let me know more?

Comment: "They" who say you must go to Spain are who?

Comment: in Dhaka, Bangladesh airport Saudi airlines immigration officers

Comment: So they're trying to deny boarding because you are not flying to Spain?  Do you have proof of onward travel from Geneva to Spain? What does your visa say in the "valid for" space?

Comment: 1. Yes that's right, they say I may come from Geneva but I have to go to Spain first! 2. No I am not going to Spain, I will be going to France. 3. Valid for 'ESPANA'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whoever told you this is wrong.  According to the Schengen Borders Code http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX:02006R0562-20131126:

> 4. By way of derogation from paragraph 1:
>
> (a) third-country nationals who do not fulfil all the conditions laid down in paragraph 1 but who hold a residence permit or a long-stay visa shall be authorised to enter the territory of the other Member States for transit purposes so that they may reach the territory of the Member State which issued the residence permit or the long-stay visa, unless their names are on the national list of alerts of the Member State whose external borders they are seeking to cross and the alert is accompanied by instructions to refuse entry or transit;

This text is an exception that allows people who would otherwise be ineligible to be admitted to other Schengen states to be admitted for the purpose of transit to the state issuing the long-stay (i.e., type D) visa.

People who *are* eligible for admission to other Schengen states fall under paragraph 1:

> 1. For intended stays on the territory of the Member States of a duration of no more than 90 days in any 180-day period, which entails considering the 180-day period preceding each day of stay, the entry conditions for third-country nationals shall be the following:
>
> (a) they are in possession of a valid travel document entitling the holder to cross the border satisfying the following criteria:
>
> (i) its validity shall extend at least three months after the intended date of departure from the territory of the Member States. In a justified case of emergency, this obligation may be waived;
>
> (ii) it shall have been issued within the previous 10 years;
>
> (b) they are in possession of a valid visa, if required pursuant to Council Regulation (EC) No 539/2001 of 15 March 2001 listing the third countries whose nationals must be in possession of visas when crossing the external borders and those whose nationals are exempt from that requirement, except where they hold a valid residence permit or a valid long-stay visa;
>
> (c) they justify the purpose and conditions of the intended stay, and they have sufficient means of subsistence, both for the duration of the intended stay and for the return to their country of origin or transit to a third country into which they are certain to be admitted, or are in a position to acquire such means lawfully;
>
> (d) they are not persons for whom an alert has been issued in the SIS for the purposes of refusing entry;
>
> (e) they are not considered to be a threat to public policy, internal security, public health or the international relations of any of the Member States, in particular where no alert has been issued in Member States' national data bases for the purposes of refusing entry on the same grounds.

As you can see, nothing in this discusses anything about a "port of entry" rule.

It is possible, however, that your visa has restrictions that prevent its use for your trip.  For example, if the visa says that it is valid for Spain plus one transit through Schengen states, you have probably already exhausted the single transit through the Schengen states, in which case you may be required to travel directly to Spain.

Comment: @eagleye see my edit.  If your visa is restricted, it's possibly not valid for travel to Switzerland.

Comment: yes I just talked with them over phone. They say as the visa is issued from Spain etc I have to go via any Spanish airport.

Comment: @eagleye perhaps you should call the Spanish consulate and (1) find out whether the visa is in fact valid for your trip and, if it is, (2) get them to explain to the airline.

Comment: Yes I will try to contact them definitely. Thanks

Comment: He's not traveling to Spain, he's going to France!

Comment: @MichaelHampton but he has a Spanish visa that would generally authorize the trip to France subject to certain possible restrictions.  The best source for information about whether the visa is valid for other Schengen states seems to be the issuing country.

Comment: Did you not see his comment stating that it is valid only for ESPANA?

Comment: @MichaelHampton I did. Paragraph I (b) quoted in this answer indicates that this long-stay visa entitles the holder to enter the Schengen area.

Comment: @MichaelHampton: Type D visas generally show the issuing country in the "valid for" field, because that's where the _full_ validity of the visa applies -- but that doesn't prevent the last part of I(b) above from applying and giving the holder rights generally equivalent to a short-stay visa in the _other_ Schengen countries.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Yes that's correct. In fact I have traveled to Italy using this visa before flying from Geneva. But now can't fly back to Geneva that's sort of wierd. And the Spanish contact no. here is unreachable.

Comment: @eagleye are you in fact resident in Spain?  Did you tell them this?  For a Spanish resident Bangladeshi flying from Bangladesh to Switzerland, TIMATIC says that visas are not required of (among others) "Passengers with a valid D visa issued by Spain for a maximum stay of 90 days."

Comment: @phoog Yes I stayed in Spain for 3 months before. I can't argue with them anymore. I bought a new ticket, going to Spain by paying more than my return trip to Geneva. And also the previous return trip to Geneva will not be refunded. So much loss for such stupid rule, I don't know who to blame!

Comment: @eagleye perhaps you can pursue civil damages against the airline.

Comment: @phoog really? do these things really work? how to?? I think I will do.

Comment: @eagleye I am not sure, but the EU generally has strong consumer protections.  Perhaps a new question is in order.

Comment: @phoog guess what. I entered in Geneva. my flight to Madrid got cancelled and i changed it to Geneva and all good! So I guess your answer is correct. wondering what should i do to saudia now for which i have lost so much money!

Comment: @eagleye look into the European union air passenger rights.